# Is there an API available to directly pull RTC data through Excel VBA?

Tags: api, excel, extract, rtc, vba

Is there a way to programmatically access Rational Team Concert data through Excel VBA?  I currently need to manually log into RTC, run a public query, then manually select the "Export to CSV" option.  Ideally, I'd like to bypass all of these manual steps and access RTC data directly (or the set of data returned from a defined query with RTC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an API, a Java one.
[This thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/96838/api-or-command-line-to-import-workitems-from-csv-to-rtc) mentions there actually two APIs (detailled in this [blog post](http://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/working-with-work-item-attributes/), once you have [setup those API](http://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/setting-up-rational-team-concert-for-api-development/)):

- The Server API that is used in the server part of RTC (and JTS)
- The Client API that is used by the Eclipse Client and the Plain Java Client Libraries

> The Plain Java Client Libraries are considerably smaller than the Client SDK and provide you with only a limited subset of the API.

But only the client SDK one seems to include the `com.ibm.team.workitem.rcp.ui.internal.wizards.inport.WorkItemImportWizard` class you would need.

That means you would need to:

> create an extension to the Eclipse client and reuse the code used in the export wizard, similar to [this blog post](http://jorgediazblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/custom-bugzilla-importer-for-non-consecutive-bug-ids/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  I read through all of the links that you provided, and it sounds like there is no pre-built "easy" way to automate the exporting of data from RTC.  As you mentioned in your reply, it sounds like an extension to the Eclipse client would be needed.  Are you aware of any posts or other resources that provide an overview or sample of the extension?  I read through the "Custom Bugzilla Importer" link, but that seemed to focus more on importing as opposed to exporting.  Thanks again!

Comment: @user3353374 the last link about "Custom Bugzilla Importer" was meant as an example of an Eclipse extension, but isn't a direct illustration on how to export. I don't know of an example illustrating *precisely* what you are looking for.